# Possible to access the Shipping_Method field through the BigCommerce API?

Tags: bigcommerce

We are trying to code an integration between our order management software (DAX) and our BigCommerce site. In order to communicate tracking #s from DAX to BC we need to be able to query the Shipping_Method field. BC has told us that we cannot set the Shipping_Method field with the current API, but this seems strange because we can set the method manually when updating orders through the back end of our site, and we're assuming that functionality comes from the API.

BC's specific response was:
"Unfortunately you cannot set the shipping_method field at this time, though this is something we are currently in discussion about in regards to exposing to the API."

Does anyone have any experience/perspective on using the shipping_method field with an integration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

BigCommerce doesn't necessarily call upon its API overtime you make a change in the software as it is most likely code invoked locally on the same server. In experience, if it isn't on the API docs you can't use it or manipulate it. It's daft the tracking number isn't available but I guess it's just the way it is at the moment.